# Apache2 - if page not found it gets served from another domain

Tags: apache-2.4, httpd.conf

I am facing a strange behavior with my main host IP and the served virtual hosts, basically I have the following:

```
|- 148.x.x.x            /var/www/html/public_html
|- domain01.com         /var/www/html/domain01.com/public_html
|- domain02.com         /var/www/html/domain02.com/public_html
|- domain03.com         /var/www/html/domain03.com/public_html
```

**Issue 01:** Now if I access any page on 148.x.x.x, <s>I get `404` http code</s>, and if the same page name hosted in `domain01.com` then the content of it displayed.

**Issue 02:** If any page is not found in other domains and it happened the same page name hosted in `domain01` then it get served.
My httpd.conf:

```
ServerRoot "/etc/httpd"
Listen 80
Include conf.modules.d/*.conf
User apache
Group apache
ServerAdmin root@localhost
ServerName 148.x.x.x:80

<Directory />
    AllowOverride none
    Require all denied
</Directory>

DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/public_html"

<Directory "/var/www">
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory "/var/www/html/public_html">
    Options All Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<IfModule dir_module>
    DirectoryIndex index.html
</IfModule>

<Files ".ht*">
    Require all denied
</Files>

ErrorLog "logs/error_log"
LogLevel warn

<IfModule log_config_module>
    LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined
    LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b" common
    <IfModule logio_module>
      LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\" %I %O" combinedio
    </IfModule>
    CustomLog "logs/access_log" combined
</IfModule>

<IfModule alias_module>
    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ "/var/www/cgi-bin/"
</IfModule>

<Directory "/var/www/cgi-bin">
    AllowOverride None
    Options None
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<IfModule mime_module>
    TypesConfig /etc/mime.types
    AddType application/x-compress .Z
    AddType application/x-gzip .gz .tgz
    AddType application/x-httpd-php .php
    AddType text/html .shtml
    AddOutputFilter INCLUDES .shtml
</IfModule>

AddDefaultCharset UTF-8

<IfModule mime_magic_module>
    MIMEMagicFile conf/magic
</IfModule>

EnableSendfile on

<IfModule mod_http2.c>
    Protocols h2 h2c http/1.1
</IfModule>

NameVirtualHost *
IncludeOptional conf.d/*.conf
IncludeOptional conf.d/domains/*.conf
```

Virtual host config:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName domain01.com
    ServerAlias www.domain01.com
    ServerAdmin webmaster@domain01
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/domain01/public_html

    <Directory /var/www/html/domain01/public_html>
        Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog /var/log/httpd/domain01-error.log
    CustomLog /var/log/httpd/domain01-access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Other domains share the same configuration.

Errors log:

```
[Sun May 10 04:35:40.554754 2020] [suexec:notice] [pid 20023] AH01232: suEXEC mechanism enabled (wrapper: /usr/sbin/suexec)
[Sun May 10 04:35:40.579226 2020] [lbmethod_heartbeat:notice] [pid 20023] AH02282: No slotmem from mod_heartmonitor
[Sun May 10 04:35:40.579272 2020] [http2:warn] [pid 20023] AH10034: The mpm module (prefork.c) is not supported by mod_http2. The mpm determines how things are processed in your server. HTTP/2 has more demands in this regard and the currently selected mpm will just not do. This is an advisory warning. Your server will continue to work, but the HTTP/2 protocol will be inactive.
[Sun May 10 04:35:40.579277 2020] [http2:warn] [pid 20023] AH02951: mod_ssl does not seem to be enabled
[Sun May 10 04:35:40.608931 2020] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 20023] AH00163: Apache/2.4.41 () PHP/7.3.16 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Sun May 10 04:35:40.608967 2020] [core:notice] [pid 20023] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/httpd -D FOREGROUND'
[Sun May 10 04:54:07.699619 2020] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 20023] AH00170: caught SIGWINCH, shutting down gracefully
[Sun May 10 04:54:08.784661 2020] [suexec:notice] [pid 20172] AH01232: suEXEC mechanism enabled (wrapper: /usr/sbin/suexec)
[Sun May 10 04:54:08.815681 2020] [lbmethod_heartbeat:notice] [pid 20172] AH02282: No slotmem from mod_heartmonitor
[Sun May 10 04:54:08.815727 2020] [http2:warn] [pid 20172] AH10034: The mpm module (prefork.c) is not supported by mod_http2. The mpm determines how things are processed in your server. HTTP/2 has more demands in this regard and the currently selected mpm will just not do. This is an advisory warning. Your server will continue to work, but the HTTP/2 protocol will be inactive.
[Sun May 10 04:54:08.815732 2020] [http2:warn] [pid 20172] AH02951: mod_ssl does not seem to be enabled
[Sun May 10 04:54:08.845184 2020] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 20172] AH00163: Apache/2.4.41 () PHP/7.3.16 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Sun May 10 04:54:08.845215 2020] [core:notice] [pid 20172] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/httpd -D FOREGROUND'
[Sun May 10 04:55:20.189266 2020] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 20172] AH00170: caught SIGWINCH, shutting down gracefully
[Sun May 10 04:55:21.262210 2020] [suexec:notice] [pid 20236] AH01232: suEXEC mechanism enabled (wrapper: /usr/sbin/suexec)
[Sun May 10 04:55:21.289998 2020] [lbmethod_heartbeat:notice] [pid 20236] AH02282: No slotmem from mod_heartmonitor
[Sun May 10 04:55:21.290044 2020] [http2:warn] [pid 20236] AH10034: The mpm module (prefork.c) is not supported by mod_http2. The mpm determines how things are processed in your server. HTTP/2 has more demands in this regard and the currently selected mpm will just not do. This is an advisory warning. Your server will continue to work, but the HTTP/2 protocol will be inactive.
[Sun May 10 04:55:21.290048 2020] [http2:warn] [pid 20236] AH02951: mod_ssl does not seem to be enabled
[Sun May 10 04:55:21.314344 2020] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 20236] AH00163: Apache/2.4.41 () PHP/7.3.16 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Sun May 10 04:55:21.314377 2020] [core:notice] [pid 20236] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/httpd -D FOREGROUND'
[Sun May 10 04:56:16.858055 2020] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 20236] AH00170: caught SIGWINCH, shutting down gracefully
[Sun May 10 04:56:17.942478 2020] [suexec:notice] [pid 20300] AH01232: suEXEC mechanism enabled (wrapper: /usr/sbin/suexec)
[Sun May 10 04:56:17.967937 2020] [lbmethod_heartbeat:notice] [pid 20300] AH02282: No slotmem from mod_heartmonitor
[Sun May 10 04:56:17.967989 2020] [http2:warn] [pid 20300] AH10034: The mpm module (prefork.c) is not supported by mod_http2. The mpm determines how things are processed in your server. HTTP/2 has more demands in this regard and the currently selected mpm will just not do. This is an advisory warning. Your server will continue to work, but the HTTP/2 protocol will be inactive.
[Sun May 10 04:56:17.967994 2020] [http2:warn] [pid 20300] AH02951: mod_ssl does not seem to be enabled
[Sun May 10 04:56:17.995419 2020] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 20300] AH00163: Apache/2.4.41 () PHP/7.3.16 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Sun May 10 04:56:17.995465 2020] [core:notice] [pid 20300] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/httpd -D FOREGROUND'
[Sun May 10 09:52:00.857620 2020] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 20300] AH00170: caught SIGWINCH, shutting down gracefully
[Sun May 10 09:52:18.179419 2020] [suexec:notice] [pid 21600] AH01232: suEXEC mechanism enabled (wrapper: /usr/sbin/suexec)
[Sun May 10 09:52:18.208499 2020] [lbmethod_heartbeat:notice] [pid 21600] AH02282: No slotmem from mod_heartmonitor
[Sun May 10 09:52:18.208546 2020] [http2:warn] [pid 21600] AH10034: The mpm module (prefork.c) is not supported by mod_http2. The mpm determines how things are processed in your server. HTTP/2 has more demands in this regard and the currently selected mpm will just not do. This is an advisory warning. Your server will continue to work, but the HTTP/2 protocol will be inactive.
[Sun May 10 09:52:18.208550 2020] [http2:warn] [pid 21600] AH02951: mod_ssl does not seem to be enabled
[Sun May 10 09:52:18.240064 2020] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 21600] AH00163: Apache/2.4.41 () PHP/7.3.16 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Sun May 10 09:52:18.240096 2020] [core:notice] [pid 21600] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/httpd -D FOREGROUND'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without knowing what the hostname is specifically, it's difficult to ascertain if this is a DNS registry issue, or a server configuration issue exactly, but there are a couple things you could update on your configuration that might help resolve the issue, or at the very least, prevent future issues if it is in fact DNS related.

On the virtual host file, you will want to make sure you have:

```sh
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName domain01.com
    ServerAlias www.domain01.com
    ServerAdmin webmaster@domain01.com
    DirectoryIndex index.html
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/domain01/public_html
    LogLevel warn
    ErrorLog /var/log/httpd/domain01-error.log
    CustomLog /var/log/httpd/domain01-access.log combined

    <Directory "/var/www/html/domain01/public_html">
        Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Where you don't ave the directory properly encased in quotes as a string, you are missing the `domain01` TLD, and you are serving the `ServerName` and `ServerAlias` entries as the same objects, without TLDs.

**Forgot to mention:**
Virtual hosts with IPs are typical served like this:

```sh
<VirtualHost 148.X.X.X>
  DocumentRoot /wwwdomain01
  ServerName www.domain01.com
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost 148.X.X.X>
  DocumentRoot /wwwdomain02
  ServerName www.domain02.com
</VirtualHost>
```

[This is a great resource](https://www.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/howto/Apache_HowToConfigure.html)

If you don't want to use the explicit IP, then you can always utilize `listen` as explained via the [apache docs](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#servername) here: [listen](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mpm_common.html#listen), and here: [virtualhost](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#virtualhost)

Comment: The host name is an IP in AWS, and it is has no DNS record, the others are sub-domains hosted in same server with DNS record of 148.x.x.x.

Comment: Got it, that wasn't clear. In that case, I would recommend the same fixes to your VirtualHost block, but with the Server name set to your IP address space and 8080 as the port...

So like `148.x.x.x:8080` as the `ServerName`

You can also utilize the `<Location URL>` block in your configuration, and this resource, is awesome for tips: https://www.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/howto/Apache_HowToConfigure.html

Comment: I am trying to server multiple domains with same IP address. After looking at the great resource you put, my configuration looks almost the same but still facing same issues.

Comment: After I explicitly set the IP address for each domain then it gets working.

Comment: There are only so many things that can go wrong if the virtualhost settings are correct. You said the IP was in AWS w/out a DNS; If you've properly setup apache, you might consider using AWS cloud watch to setup an error log capture, to figure out more details about why your container is failing to resolve. If you're using an EC2 instance, I'd also recommend setting up a [domain redirect within your AWS configuration] (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/how-to-page-redirect.html), and [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/routing-to-ec2-instance.html).

Comment: Awesome! Sorry about the last comment, didn't see your resolution note :)

Comment: Now I have another problem, please check it here: https://serverfault.com/questions/1016579/apache-vhost-loads-incorrect-document-root

Answer (score 1):

It's because virtual hosts are listening at *.  So that means any IP address configured for the server (the first configured will usually be the one to respond essentially) can serve the request.  You need to use the IP address specifically for that virtual host.