# Apache vhost loads incorrect document root

Tags: virtualhost

I setup Name-based virtual hosts, where 03 domains are hosted, my problem is when I request any page from any domain then it tries to serve it from the main host ip(15.x.x.x).

```
|- 15.x.x.x             /var/www/html/public_html
|- domain01.com         /var/www/html/apple.highschoolhelper.org/public_html
|- domain02.com         /var/www/html/orange.highschoolhelper.org/public_html
|- domain03.com         /var/www/html/avocado.highschoolhelper.org/public_html
```

My httpd.conf:

```
ServerRoot "/etc/httpd"

Listen 80

Include conf.modules.d/*.conf

User apache
Group apache

ServerAdmin root@localhost

ServerName 15.0.0.0:80

<Directory />
    AllowOverride none
    Require all denied
</Directory>

DocumentRoot "/var/www/html"

<Directory "/var/www">
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory "/var/www/html/public_html">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks

    AllowOverride None

    Require all granted
</Directory>

<IfModule dir_module>
    DirectoryIndex index.html index.php
</IfModule>

<Files ".ht*">
    Require all denied
</Files>

ErrorLog "logs/error_log"
LogLevel warn

<IfModule log_config_module>
    LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined
    LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b" common

    <IfModule logio_module>
      LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\" %I %O" combinedio
    </IfModule>

    CustomLog "logs/access_log" combined
</IfModule>

<IfModule alias_module>
    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ "/var/www/cgi-bin/"
</IfModule>

<Directory "/var/www/cgi-bin">
    AllowOverride None
    Options None
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<IfModule mime_module>
    TypesConfig /etc/mime.types

    AddType application/x-compress .Z
    AddType application/x-gzip .gz .tgz

    AddType text/html .shtml
    AddOutputFilter INCLUDES .shtml
</IfModule>

AddDefaultCharset UTF-8

<IfModule mime_magic_module>
    MIMEMagicFile conf/magic
</IfModule>

EnableSendfile on

IncludeOptional conf.d/*.conf

IncludeOptional conf.d/domains/*.conf
```

Other domains config:

```
<VirtualHost 15.0.0.0:80>
    ServerName apple.highschoolhelper.org
    ServerAlias apple.highschoolhelper.org
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/apple.highschoolhelper.org/public_html
    ServerAdmin webmaster@apple.highschoolhelper.org
    DirectoryIndex index.html index.php
    LogLevel warn

    <Directory /var/www/html/apple.highschoolhelper.org/public_html>
                IndexIgnoreReset ON
                IndexIgnore .well-known

        Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog /var/log/httpd/apple.highschoolhelper.org-error.log
    CustomLog /var/log/httpd/apple.highschoolhelper.org-access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Update:
This lines I see in access_log, it seems the `apple` domain get requested:

```
41.x.x.x  15.x.x.x - - [11/May/2020:04:54:00 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 403 3630 "-" "Mozilla/5.0"
41.x.x.x  apple.highschoolhelper.org - - [11/May/2020:04:54:06 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 403 3630 "-" "Mozilla/5.0"
41.x.x.x  apple.highschoolhelper.org - - [11/May/2020:04:54:06 +0000] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 196 "-" "Mozilla/5.0"
```

Comment: I am not sure if an IP Address can be used as a ServerName. In most cases it should be set to the default domain name.

Comment: @AdmiralNoisyBottom I tried disable it but same problem.

Comment: The 403 indicates access forbidden. You also have -indexes meaning if there is no index.html or index.php page then a 403 will be returned. Does an index page exist? Just a thought.

Comment: In addition, make certain any files within the domain folders are not owned by root. They should be owned by the apache user or another user with access. Not root.

Comment: @AdmiralNoisyBottom All files are `chown` apache, and index file is exist there.

Comment: The 403 code in your log is a big clue to what is going on. Somewhere along the line the request is denied. Is there a .htaccess file in the folders which might be denying access. The 403 is the biggest problem I see.

Comment: @AdmiralNoisyBottom No, currently all virtual hosts have only an index page.